# Python: How to access MySQL DB table using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python

I am making a python GUI that will look up the the status of a helpdesk ticket in a MySQL database. I connected python to an existing MySQL database with SQLAlchemy using the code below.

```
conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='root',
                               password='stuff',host='127.0.0.1',
                               database='mydb')
c = conn.cursor()
```

I only need access to one of the columns, `ticket_id`,  in a table called `tickets`. Basically I want to do this:

```
SELECT ticket_status FROM  tickets WHERE ticket_id = 123;
```

What would be simplest way to do this?

Comment: This seems to be using the official [mysql.connector](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/) package, not SQLAlchemy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should work at fetching a single value. If you realize later you need to fetch more than one value you can change fetchone() to fetchall()

```
try:

    sql = '''
        SELECT ticket_status FROM tickets WHERE ticket_id = 123
                '''
    c.execute(sql)
    result = c.fetchone()
except Exception as e:
    raise Exception(e)
```